# I can't getting text, string variable from textview.gettext()

Tags: android, textview, gettext

```
 class JavaScriptInterface  {   
                        private TextView contentView;   
                        public JavaScriptInterface(TextView aContentView) {  
                            contentView = aContentView;
                            }  

                    @JavascriptInterface
                    public void processContent(String aContent) {   
                        final String content = aContent;  
                        contentView.post(new Runnable() {      
                            public void run() {  
                                contentView.setText(content);  
                                contentView.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY); 
                            }       
                        });  
                    }   
                }   

              TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source);

              JavaScriptInterface jv = new JavaScriptInterface(tv2);
              webview1.addJavascriptInterface(jv, "INTERFACE"); 
              webview1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){  

                @Override   
                public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {  view.loadUrl("javascript:window.INTERFACE.processContent(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerText);");  
                }   
            });  

             webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('txtuName').value='"+s_ogrNo+"'");
             webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('txtUPassGorunen').value='"+s_parola+"'");
             webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('txtSecCode').value='"+s_captcha+"'");
             webview1.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('btnLogin')[0].click();");
String tviewtext = tv2.getText().toString();
// i can see source code on textview, but i can't getting string variable this line.
```

Comment: Did you set the text somewhere (in xml maybe)? What do you get? And **please** take the time to format the code in your questions...this is ugly!

Comment: Sorry, i am new user. I learning.

Comment: It's ok, just remember to do that. That's why I just commented for now instead of downvoting. Now, about you setting the text...

Comment: I can get source code on textview.Later, i can't get string variable from textview text. Thank's for help.

Comment: What happens? Error? How do you know you aren't getting the value?

Comment: i can see value on textview but, "String tviewtext = tv2.getText().toString();" this line not working.

Comment: **How** isn't it working exactly?

Comment: tviewtext Variable is null.

Answer (score 0):

well if your textview variable is null, then this basically means that this

```
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source);
```

does not return a valid TextView.

To understand why it doesnt we will need the xml containing the TextView.

Also i would appreciate the whole class in which you are trying to retreive the TextView, because your `class JavsScriptInterface` does not appear to extend Activity.

Provide full code and xml if you want any further help

Comment: `TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.source);
 JavaScriptInterface jv = new JavaScriptInterface(tv2);
 webview1.addJavascriptInterface(jv, "INTERFACE");` This code is provide value for textview. But i can't get string variable this value.

Comment: obviously tv2 is null. so the way you inflate your view is off or at least you are looking for tv2 in the wrong view, cant help without your code